# Unable to read data from the transport connection (StreamReader)

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a StreamReader listening to an IP port and running in a thread / loop, this is working correctly (C#, Visual Studio) -

```
ns = tc.GetStream();
sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ns);

private void ReceiveData()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                messageId = sr.ReadLine();
                bool flag = messageId.Length <= 31;
                if (!flag)
                {
                    messageId = messageId.Substring(20, 12);
                    m_search.m_queue.add(messageId);
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
```

I wish to send back some characters and so I create a StreamWriter (in a separate .cs and so I have to reference the underlying stream variable in the first .cs)

```
var xs = Socketclient.ns;
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(xs))
                        {
                            sw.Write("TH1\r\n");
                            sw.Flush();

                            //Wait 3 secs then deactivate relay
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                            sw.Write("TH0\r\n");
                            sw.Flush();
                        }
               }
```

Which works until it 'returns' (after the last sw.Flush();) and reports Unable to read data from the transport connection here -

```
messageId = sr.ReadLine();
```

I assume I need to run my StreamWriter in a different thread or I need some way of suspending / restarting StreamReader whilst StreamWriter runs.

According to various sites StreamWriter should not affect StreamReader but it does and seems to close the underlying stream (ns) when finished.

Thoughts appreciated.

Regards

Comment: The constructor you are using for StreamWriter will close the undelyng stream when disposed. There are contructor overloads with a boolean parameter to prevent the underlying stream to be messed with.

Comment: Thanks, C. Gonzalez, would appreciate being pointed to some examples

Comment: Instead of using sw = new Streamwriter(xs) you could use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg712853(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I think that only works when you are sending files, are there any examples writing direct to a TCP port?